# php и неактивированный mbstring

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Установил phmyadmin. После установки он мне выдал: The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.
Проверив модули php увидел что mbstring присутствует[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ок, подумал я и решил глянуть на phpinfo(). И действительно в phpinfo() показывает, что его нет. При попытки установить mbstring php выдает, что установлен.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, в conf.d я прекрасно вижу симлинк на mbstring.ini.
Все что нашел по этому поводу не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения проблемы попробуйте:

1. Перегрузите FPM.
2. В конфиге надо также попробовать его найти и раскомментировать